# ng-table merge column header with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am tring merge column with ng-table

if I want merge table header with ng-table ,

I search about ng-table's doc , but there is nothing,

I found html attribute cloumnspan , but I want merge table header,

```
</td>
<td data-title="'Funds'" sortable="funds" style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
    {{user.funds}}
</td>
<td data-title="'Funds'" sortable="funds" style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
    {{user.funds}}
</td>
```

but ng-table has no  on it , how can I do it to merge header?

please help

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML similar to they have done here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html for structure named as 
"A test table with merged cells"

```
/-----------------------------------------\
|          |      Average      |   Red    |
|          |-------------------|  eyes    |
|          |  height |  weight |          |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  Males   | 1.9     | 0.003   |   40%    |
|-----------------------------------------|
| Females  | 1.7     | 0.002   |   43%    |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

Keep **second row for header** text (no height or weigh) **empty** but bind the data to columns as per model.

Other way around may be to create a new property by merging data of two properties in model and make single column with header in table.

Hope those ideas will help you. Thanks.